# How cellular automata simulations are not in violation with the Second Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, cellular-automaton

Cellular automaton models sometimes gives rise to ordered systems (hence, having lower entropy than at its initial state). So, it is in 'apparent' violation of the second law of thermodynamics. Can somebody explain how such violation doesn't occur at all?

Comment: I think that the key is that thermodynamics are defined for equilibrium states. Are your cellular automatons in an equilibrium state, or maybe in non-equillibrium stationary state?

Comment: I think that in general cellular automata systems and real world systems are quite different things. Set aside the 2nd law of thermodynamics for now. I don't think that there is even any attempt to conserve energy or even define an energy-like parameter in any cellular automata systems I've seen. Or how about conserving momentum or even defining momentum in cellular automata systems?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Cellular automata can represent real systems. The FHP cellular automata is designed specifically in order to conserve momentum and energy, since in the continuum limit it is able to reproduce Navier-Stokes equations. There is also CA approaches for chemical and excitable systems where convservation of quantities is important. Cellular automata are a good way to make models in physics and other disciplines also, so they are as real as any other equation or model.

Comment: @VictorSeven - Thanks for the info. I'm not surprised to hear that cellular automata have been used to represent real physical systems by including physical concepts, parameters, and conservation laws such as momentum and energy. And for such "physics-mimicking" cellular automata systems, I wouldn't be surprised to hear that the 2nd Law of thermodynamics is obeyed, too. But it sounds like the OP is asking about cellular automata systems in general including simple systems such as the well known "Game of Life".

Comment: @SamuelWeir In that kind of cases, I think it is difficult to say. That is why I didn't answered directly the question, because I am  not sure (and I have not read anything) of that cases.  I suspect it is related with non-equilibrium stuff, but it is my bet.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I am referring to general celular automata systems as Victor pointed out.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I think your first comment is quite helpful. So for example, take an elementary cellular automata such as the one in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZmiVJSoh1g, which leads to the generation of random patterns as time progresses. Is it even sensible to associate the concept of entropy with such a model?

Comment: @Maneet - You can certainly define an entropy parameter to such a cellular automata system as the one you show, but just because you define an entropy-like parameter doesn't automatically mean that it obeys the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics. In the "Game of Life" cellular automata system, you can start of with a random arrangements of dots, but if you let the simulation run you'll generally end up with some stable patterns. So if we were to define an entropy parameter, it would probably decrease when applied to that system.

Comment: @SamuelWeir You greatly captured what I was trying to ask. So in that Game of Life simulation what reasoning can we give to justify the violation of second law? I understand that second law holds for isolated systems. So if we consider the universe as an isolated system, I guess we can explain this observation by saying that: due to the heat released by the computer/chip/machine there is net increase in entropy of universe (our system: computer and its surroundings) even though the end state of the simulation has lower entropy.  What if we consider just the computer as an isolated system?

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is too low to provide comments, so thus the answer box.  I am a little bit lost as to your premise. Entropy is a **real** world  phenomenon, but a computer model can have any number of hand picked parameters, you don't have to worry about real physical consequences.

My concern in this reply is that you are referring to entropy and its relation  to information, although you have no related  tags, so if that's the case I am out of my depth. But please clarify this for people with more experience than I.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I have found what I was looking for here: http://sjsu.rudyrucker.com/~kwanghyung.paek/paper/

Comment: Take in account that order can come from disorder, even in real scenarios, not only simulated ones. For example, bird flocking or fireflies sinchronization. Also, in the Ising model, for low $T$, the final state is an ordered one, for example. So this is not related with computer stuff.

Comment: @VictorSeven Where does disorder lie in the case of birds flocking? And if in this case (birds' flocking) order comes from disorder, how do we explain that the second law is still not violated?

Comment: @Maneet To have entropy decrease you have to input energy. For birds, they use biochemical energy to move their wings and cause more order, lower external entropy. But the entropy inside the birds increased with the biochemical fuel burning, and also the entropy of atmospheric particles gotten knocked around by the wings increased entropy. It is energy, and then also what you consider the system.

Comment: @Maneet For the case of birds, I think Bob's commet is good.  In any case, I get again the example of the Ising model at low $T$: you can start at complete disorder, but it will order, up to the equilibrium state. And this is the energy minimum.